# Infer material characteristics from atoms/molecules configuration

Tags: atomic-physics, molecules

I'm not an expert in this field but I always wonder how deep is our knowledge about atoms and molecules from the point of view of the resulting material characteristics.

The first example that comes in mind is the periodic table: is it possible to expect the actual behavior of the elements relying only on the atoms configuration (i.e. atomic number, electron configuration, etc...)?

To better explain my thoughts I try to provide an example in a different context. Let's say we want to predict the mechanical properties of groups of magnetics marbles. Even without observing them before, we can accurately infer their mechanical characteristics from their setup. I.e. if we have only 1 marble, we know it can roll in any direction. If we have 2, they can easily roll along their axis only. If we have 3, they cannot roll at all, and so on. With a more detailed analysis we can infer their behavior even for *unknown* or more complex configurations.

Can we do the same with atoms or molecules?
Can we infer the behavior and characteristics of, say, water just knowing the "shape" of its molecule?

Comment: Have you heard of chaos theory? If you have, then you might try tinkering with your idea using the initial value problems of the theory. If you have not, go check it out! Then let me know what you think...

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explained well my question or I don't understand the chaos theory. I'm not interested in the forecast of a local state of the system. I'm talking about the *characteristics* of a material. Why water boils at 100 °C or freezes at 0 °C (ok, more or less)? Or why some elements are gases? Can these things be inferred from the atomic configuration without experiments and observations?

Comment: First, a single molecule of water doesn't boil. It's the ensemble that boils. Now, in am ensemble, there will be a huge number of water molecules, and the bulk property can be inferred if we know how each and every molecule starts from and how they interact. You would still need to know the hydrogen bond interactions and van der wall forces, and these are mostly experimental. So many factors come into play that prediction is almost impossible and this is where chaos theory comes in ( we can't even predict the actual motion of a double pendulum given everything, it's so sensitive. Same here ):)

Comment: Btw, after some work, I remembered this. Freezing is basically the breakage of some weak bonds and forming of new bonds. The number of particles actually is a factor in this. Fewer particles might form different bonds than more particles. Again, this means that the initial state is very much necessary for knowing what we want to predict.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need the initial values (that are bound to a specific instance) while we are talking about general properties of a material.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72081/150769 check this out

Comment: Yes you can deduce / calculate characteristics of any sort. But almost so and just in principle. I think the question is broad and you could refine it. Consider that even materials as polymers are modelled for their rheology. Computations based on the knowledge of the constituents are indeed a big challenge both for theoretical and technical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The periodic table came about in the reverse manner: regularities were noted by Mendeleev, who suggested a scheme that put elements so that chemical properties follow a somewhat simple pattern. Later it was discovered why that pattern holds (the electron shell structure). To some extent this allows you to predict things - if I have a halogen you can predict what kinds of salt it would form with alkaline metals, and if I have a noble gas atom you will predict that it won't react with anything... except that if my halogen is astatine it will be too unstable to react to anything, and if my noble gas is [oganesson it might not even have a traditional electron shell structure](https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/immense-oganesson-projected-to-have-no-electron-shells/3008104.article). There are limits of applicability to simple systems.

Now, you could just solve the (relativistic) Schrödinger equation for an atom get its electron structure (perhaps after doing the even hairier modelling of nuclear stability just in case I start talking about astatine again), and if you want to really overdo it you will run a quantum simulation of the atom-to-atom interactions. This cannot be done analytically even for small atoms (each electron adds 3 dimensions to the problem) and you will have to do some very tricky quantum calculations. Most are approximations like [the Hartree-Fock method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method), and computationally [hard](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys1415) and expensive (I have heard that $O(N^7)$ algorithms are used). But it can be done in principle, and [people do it for real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum_chemistry_and_solid-state_physics_software). It is just that it is very, very messy and if you try it for sufficiently weird systems the results will be wrong - one has to know the limits of applicability of one's software too.

In practice there are useful rules of thumb and simplifications. For some systems you can treat atoms and bonds using classical physics and ignore the quantum stuff when simulating them. For most standard chemistry you can predict that elements in the same column of the periodic table will form similar compounds and often have the same properties - if [organoselenium compounds are smelly](http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2012/05/15/things_i_wont_work_with_selenophenol), so are likely organotellurium compounds. For important molecules like water people and atoms like carbon have taken care to study the electron orbital behavior to great extent. But much depends on the degree of precision you want and need.

A final point: chaos theory is usually not relevant here, unless you get to relatively floppy molecules or ones with a lot of mobile electrons. The unpredictability is not due to small differences in initial conditions growing exponentially (chaos), but the fact that the eigenvalue spectra are complex and if a particular orbital state has lower energy than another the shape and hence behaviour will be different. In a deep sense the randomness is [mathematical randomness](http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~km9/Randomness%20and%20Mathematical.pdf) - fixed by the rules of math, but there may not be much pattern to it.

In the end, predicting marbles is much easier than atoms and molecules because they have fewer moving parts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least in theory. There are many practical challenges though.

From a purely theoretical perspective it is easy. Ignoring nuclear reactions, all behavior of electrons and nuclei can be explained using the laws of electrodynamics and quantum mechanics. However, for materials more complicated than a hydrogen atom, these calculations quickly become very difficult.

One therefore typically uses simplifications that make calculations easier. One often made assumption is the Born Oppenheimer approximation. This is based of the fact that the motion of the nuclei and of the electrons occur at very different time scales. One can therefore solve the problem of motion of the atoms separately from the motion of the electrons.

For solids one typically uses some additional simplifications incorporated in theoretical framework called density functional theory (DFT). One then assumes the nuclei to form a certain lattice. Then one calculates the energy of the electrons in the electric field created by these nuclei. This process is repeated for various lattice configurations. The lattice with the lowest energy will be the lattice formed by the actual atoms. This way one can calculate the atomic structure of a material.

With this information you also know how much energy it costs to deform the material.

The electronic states corresponding to the found atomic structure give information about the conductivity and magnetic properties of the material. These are all properties at zero Kelvin.

One can then calculate the possible vibrations in this lattice and the influence of these vibrations on the electronic structure. This gives you information about the temperature dependence of the material properties.

However, also these calculation are computationally heavy. So they are typically only done for simple molecules or for materials consisting of many identical atoms. Even then experiments are indispensable to check whether the assumptions were valid.